# javascript ternary operator to count characters in a string

Tags: javascript

I recently came across this javascript function to count the number of times a certain character appears in a string.
I can see it uses the .replace() method replacing a regex of any non white space but I cant quite understand what it's being replaced with.

```
function Char_Counts(str1) {
    var uchars = {};
    str1.replace(/\S/g, function(l) {
        uchars[l] = (isNaN(uchars[l]) ? 1 : uchars[l] + 1);
    });
    return uchars;
}
console.log(Char_Counts("This is a sample string"));
```

Can anyone please explain what the argument "l" is that is being passed to the unnamed function and exactly what is happening inside the ternary operator, I manged to achieve the same effect as this but using nested for loops, but I can't even see how this is even iterating through the strings characters. This is the output in the console I just want to understand exactly what is happening.

```
Object { T: 1, h: 1, i: 3, s: 4, a: 2, m: 1, p: 1, l: 1, e: 1, t: 1, 3 more… }
```

Comment: that is the matched character in the string... since you are using `\S` it is each non space character

Comment: The  ternary checks if the character is already present in the object, if yes, increment counter else set to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what is going on on the function is this

```
function Char_Counts(str1) {  
  //Create an object where we will hold the letters and thier counts
  var uchars = {};

  // Get all non space characters matched with /\S/g regex
  str1.replace(/\S/g, function (l) {

  // here l represents each character as the regex matches it
  // so finally the ternary operator assings to the letter property of our map: if we find the letter for the first time isNaN will return true from isNan(undefined) and we will assing 1 otherwise we will increase the count by 1
  uchars[l] = (isNaN(uchars[l]) ? 1 : uchars[l] + 1);
  });
  return uchars;  
}
```

So for an example run in the string `These Ones` the regex will match any non space character so `TheseOnes`, the `l` in the function will be `T` then `h` then `e` etc.

`uchars['T']` is `undefined` so `isNaN(undefined)` gives `true`
so we set `uchars['T'] = 1;`

***the ternary operator returns the evaluated expression after `?` if the first statement is true otherwise returns the evaluated expression after `:`***

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/el/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

> condition ? expr1 : expr2
>
> if condition is true, the operator returns the value of expr1;
>   otherwise, it returns the value of expr2.

Another way to do this would be with `Array#reduce`

```
function Char_Counts(str){
  return str.replace(/\s/g, "").split("").reduce(function(prev, current){
    if(!(current in prev)){ prev[current] = 1} else { prev[current]++}
    return prev;
  }, {})
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is unusual to do it like this. Actually this pattern is more used. It gets either the truthy value of `uchars[l]` or `0` and adds one.

```
uchars[l] = (uchars[l] || 0) + 1;
```